# ubuntu 14.04.4 with kernel 4.2: black screen instead of the login screen after installing nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, nvidia-geforce

I am new to ubuntu and I want to install cuda 7.5 on my computer, but I met problems when I tried to install nvidia driver. I have tried many times and many methods, all failed. 
For example, I tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
```

But I got a black screen instead of the login screen. I have tried all possible drivers, but none worked. The nvidia driver on my dual graphics laptop is **GeForce 840M**, and my system  is:

- ubuntu 14.04.4 with linux kernel 4.2.0-30-generic.

To get into system, I have to run `sudo prime-select intel`, then I run the following commands after reboot:

When I run `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`in termal, the information is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06)
  Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:5040]
  Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M [10de:1341] (rev ff)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5227] (rev 01)
  Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:5028]
```

Comment: Does the terminal show any errors when you install a driver. I suggest purging all custom drivers from ppa, run `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa && sudo apt-get update` and then install a driver from Ubuntu repos `sudo apt-get install nvidia-352`. If there are any errors, please post the output.

Comment: @Pilot6, The terminal didn't show any errors. And I just could't see the login screen, I mean that I could get into **ttf1** normally by `ctrl+alt+f1` and see nvidia-driver installed on my computer.

Comment: So you installed `nvidia-352` with no errors? Does `prime-select` work? Run `sudo prime-select intel`.

Comment: @Pilot6, `prime-select` does work.

Comment: What does it show? Does it allow to switch adapters. After you switch to Intel, reboot and test. If it runs OK, then try to switch to nvidia.

Comment: And BTW did you try to install bumblebee? If you did, that may be the problem.

Comment: @Pilot6, I test several times. When I select intel, I can see the login screen and  everything is normal. But after I switch to nvidia, I again can only have the black screen.  And I have never tried to install bumblebee, Should I install bumbebee?

Comment: No, bumblebee is no good. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: It looks like there is a compatibility problem with your graphics card. I suggest reporting this bug to launchpad. Meanwhile you can use the Intel adapter.

Comment: According to your output the driver did not install properly, or this specific adapter is not supported for some reason. Please run another command and replace the output. `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`. This way the code will be shown.

Comment: @Pilot6, Thank you very much, I will use the Intel adapter  and switch to nvidia when I really have the need.

Comment: And also please run `sudo apt-get purge bumblebee` Maybe you did not notice how you installed it. And reboot.

Comment: This adapter IS supported and should work. You either installed bumblebee, or the kernel module did not build. You should have noticed an error.

Comment: @Pilot6, I have checked, I didn't install bumblebee.

Comment: Then you did not install the nvidia module properly. It is not loaded.

Comment: I dont't know what happend, it is all the same after I reinstalled nvidia-driver.

Comment: Is it shown as `Kernel driver in use:`?

Comment: @Pilot6, sorry, it wasn't shown as Kernel driver.  But when I installed nvidia and didt't swicth to intel, it was shown as Kernel driver in use. I have to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue.
Create file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with next content:

```
Section "Device"
 Identifier "Card0"
 Driver "Intel"
 Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
EndSection
```

This solution helped me and I hope this will help you

Comment: This solution worked for me on ThinkPad P70 with Quadro M600M. Thanks!

Comment: This solution also worked for me, thanks very much!

Comment: Also works with ThinkPad T560 (GeForce 940MX).

Answer (score -1):

Try disabling uefi and use legacy bios if possible and then install ubuntu. The installer for ubuntu 16.04 tells that propriatary drivers might have problems with uefi and using legacy bios fixed the black screen problem for me with nvidia drivers on a dual graphics laptop.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is not relevant at all. Ant UEFI is not related at all.

Comment: Perhaps not, although i had the same problem on ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04 and it started to work when UEFI was disabled.